# How to change the theme color of default fragment dialog

Tags: android

I have shown a dialog fragment. I have done it, but I want to change background (Theme) color grey to white.

[image]
My dialog code:

```
public class TestDialog extends DialogFragment {

public static TestDialog newInstance() {
    return new TestDialog();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.MyDialog);
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return container;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            //setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.MyDialog);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dailog_fragment, null))
    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            TestDialog.this.getDialog().cancel();
        }
    });      
    return builder.create();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got The Solution:

I am using below style theme for set the white background color.

```
<style name="MyFragment">
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    </style>
```

We can also use Holo Theme

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileEditActionBar.this, AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT);
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.MyDialog);
```

and then make the custom `MyDialog` style.

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="MyDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/orange_transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

note that it should be in `style.xml`.

Comment: are you setting the `setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.MyDialog);` in the `OnCreate` ?

Comment: did u add the things in style.xml ?

Comment: change         <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/orange_transparent</item>
 to any color you want #xxxxxx

Comment: this     setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.MyDialog);
 should be in oncreatedialog not oncreate(bundle)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38615/discussion-between-hharry-and-ahmed-ekri)

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file, the activity definition of the dialog activity, add the `android:theme` attribute as follows.

```
<activity
        android:name=".YourActivityName"

        android:theme="@styles/style"

        />
```